# How to Modify App Crashing Dialog?

Tags: android

I was reading the [Writing Style Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/writing.html) provided by Google until I saw this:

[image: snapshot from the site]

What I understand from this example is: you can modify the crashing message that appears when your app crashes. Is this true? Is it possible to change the crashing dialog text? Or is it just a not-real example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this true?

By establishing a top-level exception handler, yes. See `Thread` and `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.

Comment: And the `not responding` message is counted as an exception, right?

Comment: @iturki: Actually, that's a good question. I do not know if the ANR ("Application Not Responding", the old message that would appear for this) triggers an exception that `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` would cover. I was not paying close enough attention to the actual words in the dialog and was thinking it was a standard crash dialog. My apologies.

Comment: It is Ok. I was asking about the Crash dialogs but I just want to know if ANR dialogs are covered too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's what Google themselves changed through various versions. In GingerBread I would get the "wrong" force close dialog, in ICS the "right" one.

They're now using it as an example for other developers - learn from other people's  'mistakes'.